# How can I disable this in cmd?

Tags: drivers, keyboard, cmd.exe, graphics, gpedit

Right basically I had a glitching laptop keyboard, even with an external, it still persisted. I uninstalled my default keyboard and enabled 'Prevent Installation of Devices not described by other policy settings' so that when I restarted it wouldn't automatically be installed.

However I was playing around in Device manager, and accidentally deleted my graphics driver + files with it. I can still start up my computer and stuff but what I want to know is how to disable 'Prevent Installation of Devices not described by other policy settings' that option using cmd? My laptop screen is broken too and I can't use an external screen due to my uninstalled graphics driver (RGB isn't working) and I have to rely on typing and thus cmd.

Plsss help 
Thanks

Comment: Are you able to use a 2nd computer and use RDP or teamviewer, etc. to remote connect to the computer? I'd go for such approach if possible.

Comment: Yeah I can? Thank you so much for your reply. LP Chip. But if I were to set up a remote connection for my other computer.. how can I do that with a broken screen? For that laptop I normally use something as an external montor but obviously right now that's not working through RGB..I just have important files there ^^

Comment: If you can remote into your laptop from an external device, you will be able to view the desktop through it, and thus perform everything you need to do.

Comment: Yeah but I would still need settings from the laptop (IP address, allow remote desktop settings etc..?)

Comment: Thats why I asked, have you previously set that up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Safe Mode**

This gives you access to a VGA driver.

If the above doesn't help.

Use Safe Mode with Networking if you need internet access.

Click *Start - All Programs - Accessories - Run* and type

```
msconfig
```

Then go to the Boot tab and click Safe Boot (also tick Network if needed). Reboot. Come back here and untick Safe Boot to return to normal mode.

or

If your computer has a single operating system installed, repeatedly press the **F8** key as your computer restarts. You need to press **F8** before the Windows logo appears. If the Windows logo appears, you will need to try again. [From *Start - Help and Support*]

**Startup Repair**

This also can give you a command prompt.

If your computer has a single operating system installed, repeatedly press the F8 key as your computer restarts. You need to press F8 before the Windows logo appears. If the Windows logo appears, you will need to try again. [From Start - Help and Support].

On the Advanced Boot Options screen, use the arrow keys to highlight Repair your computer, and then press **ENTER**.

Select Startup Repair.

Startup repair makes a log file. See `C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt`.

To access if Windows won't start, on the Advanced Boot Options screen, use the arrow keys to highlight Repair your computer, and then press ENTER.

Select Command Prompt. (this is where you can undo anything)

Type

```
type C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt |more
```

### .

Comment: Sorry but before I try any of above, what exactly is it trying to do and how it fits in with my situation? ^^

Comment: It tells you in the second line of each section. *This gives you access to a VGA driver* and *This also can give you a command prompt.*

Comment: Look in your BIOS, it MIGHT have an option re monitor to use.

Comment: Not having a monitor isn't a problem if you know what to type. Do you have another computer to write down the steps?